# htaccess renaming .php files to .html files giving file not found errors?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm using this code to rewrite my php files to be html files, so **technical.php** would appear as **technical.html**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

but it gives me a 404 error when visiting technical.html

```
Not Found

The requested URL /technical.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Did I get the order wrong in my htaccess?

Comment: I know this is probabaly the first thing you checked, but does the technical.php file actually exist in the same dir as the .htaccess file?

Comment: it is, yes. The php file is in a directory called clients if that makes a difference?

Comment: Uh, and the .htaccess file is ***also*** in the clients dir, right?

Comment: Do I just need one in the root, or every folder?

Comment: You can get by with just the .htaccess rule in the root folder, unless you have subfolders that override the provided RewriteRule. However, from what I can see what you have should work. Provided you're trying to map /clients/technical.html to load /clients/technical.php. If you're trying to get /technical.html to load /clients/technical.php, then you'd need to specify the folder as part of the Rewrite Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an .htaccess rule in the subfolder the files were in fixed this! I thought one .htaccess in the root, controlled the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll have to specify the app folder as well:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ appFolder/$1.php
```

Comment: This also does not work. Does it need to be `RewriteRule appFolder/^(.*)\.html$ appFolder/$1.php`